# basic question on definition of function

Tags: soft-question

on wikipedia it says that a function is a relation or process that associates each x of X an element y of Y. I can understand how a function is a relation defined by some equation but can't really understand the interpretation as a process.

Is it necessary to understand this and if so could someone make this clearer for me, thanks

Comment: In France there is two related definitions, functions and applications: your definition corresponds to application because the domain of the function is ALL the set X while, for example the real function $f(x)=\dfrac 1x$ is not defined in $x=0$. In other words, many times you are concerned with an expression for which you have to define the domain of it while for your function the domain is given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More precisely by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) given $2$ sets $X$ and $Y$ a function $f:X\to Y$ is a "law" which associates to any value $x\in X$ ***one and only one*** value $y\in Y$.

Note that we don't need that $f$ is defined by an explicit formula or expression the definiton indeed works in a more general context.

For example we can consider the function $f$ which associates to any person the mother.

Or in a more mathematical context, we can consider the function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ which associates to any natural number $n$ the corresponding $n^{th}$ prime number.

Refer also to the related

- [What exactly is a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2862927/505767)
- [Why is $\sin : \mathbb{R} \to [-5,5] $ different from $\sin : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2866897/505767)

Comment: thanks, if a function is a law then would that not imply that say f(x)=x+1     is the function?

Comment: @JamesAnthony We always need to specify the in which sets we are considering the law, so $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x+1$ is a function.

Comment: So is function not a product of the law

Comment: @JamesAnthony I've added some link where the topic is discussed in great detail.