# Is $xy=0$ a function?

Tags: functions

Graphically, it passes the vertical line test. However, I am confused because for $x=0$, there are infinite $y$ values that satisfy $xy=0$. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: It is not. Let $x=0$. What $y$ value does this "function" output?

Comment: @RushabhMehta thank you!

Comment: "for x=0, there are infinite y values that satisfy xy=0": so it does not pass the vertical line test, does it?

Comment: @RushabhMehta It is not a function as a general statement is not completely correct. We need to specify which domain we are referring to. For $x\neq 0$ it defines indeed the finction $y=0$.

Comment: Maybe I am being pedantic, but I don't think that the question is well-posed.  A vital part of the definition of a function is a specification of the domain and codomain of that function.  In this case, are we to assume that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers?  integers?  complex numbers?  something else?  If they are real numbers, do we allow *any* real numbers, or some subset of real numbers?  Moreover, a pedantic and snarky response to your question is "No, it is an equation, not a function."  Perhaps the question is "Does the equation $xy=1$ define a function $y$ in terms of $x$?"

Comment: If that is the question, the domain becomes important.  For example, the answer could be "Yes.  The equation defines a function $y(x) = 1/x$ on the domain $(0,\infty)$."

Comment: @RushabhMehta What about my consideration? Do you agree with that?

Comment: @gimusi yes, I agree

Comment: @RushabhMehta That's nice! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a function of one variable it is not (in general) a function, indeed recall that by definition

$$f:A\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\quad\forall x\in A \quad \exists! y \quad y=f(x)$$

and, as noticed by Rushabh Mehta, for $x=0$ we have that $y$ can assume any value.

It would be a function, in implicit form, if we assume for example

$$f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}$$

which correspons to the function $y=0$ with domain $x\neq 0$.

Refer also to the related

- [basic question on definition of function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2902581/505767)

Answer (score 0):

It is not a function (as it was pointed out in a comment), but a relation, like a circle (a set of ordered pairs): $R=\{(x,y)|xy=0\}$.